# Firebase admin firestore error: 'Query' object has no attribute 'stream'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm unable to query a firebase firestore database from the python admin sdk.

Right now I'm trying to query using `stream` like the docs say:

```
db.collection('myDatabase').where(
    'ticker', '==', variable['ticker']).where(
    'type', '==', variable['type']).stream()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:
`'Query' object has no attribute 'stream'`
What must I do to query correctly the firestore db

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue.  My problem was that I was using `db.collection(u'cars).document(u'blue).get()`.  I kept getting an error of Client 'Query' object has no attribute get().

My problem was that when I am creating this db.collection object, I have to use lists in order to allow for instances where I have sub-collections.  If you have the most up to date firebase-admin and you still get this error, verify that your query object is valid.  Mine was coming up with None but still created a `<google.cloud.firestore_v1.transaction.Transaction object at XXXXX>`

I would check that your collection name exists, and that your client app is initialized.

```
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    db = firestore.Client()
```

tldr: verify client app started and that your search should return at least one document.

Answer (score 0):

You might be on an older version of the python library. `stream()` used to be called `get()`. Make sure you are on the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade firebase-admin
```